# Magento-show custom attribute of a product only if that belongs to specific category

Tags: magento-1.9

I am showing a specific attribute on product page directly under short description instead of additional information section. I am able to achieve that but I want to show particular attribute only for products from a specific category. Not for all products from other categories. I need some IF statement here to show this only for specific category, for example cat ID 7. Anybody can help?

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('fabric') ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$category_id = 7;
if(in_array($category_id, $_product->getCategoryIds())){
   echo $_product->getAttributeText('fabric')
}
```

Comment: nope, not working, not showing any result at all.

Comment: For me, I am able to get the value of attribute with the code I have in my question or maybe I am not understanding you.

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($_product->getCategoryIds());`?

Comment: Strange, I am getting no result for desired product, but getting cat ID perfectly for all other products.

Comment: the print value in products of other categories is Array ( [0] => 10 ) and in product that I want to show, is Array ( )

Comment: Did you check your product admin to make sure it is assign to multiple category  and that all your index are up to date? Also is this a simple or configureable product?

Comment: Yes, I checked everything, but I got it worked with other code, posting it as answer. anyways, thank you for great effort. for some reason this code does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The code that worked for me is this, posting here as answer if this is needed by anyone and other codes didnt work for them.

```
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();?>
<?php if($category->getId()==7): ?>
<?php echo "a is a" ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Magento-1.9, Display the custom attribute settings

**Magento Admin Panel** -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> Add Attribute ->

**Frontend Properties** -> Visible on Product View Page on Front-end here select the "Yes" option.

Once you can try this method.